# Appropriate Response to a User Contacting you via Facebook

Tags: discussion

Last night, I answered a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36808611/pyqt-slot-execute-many-times/36809167#36809167) on StackOverflow. I then went to sleep and was planning to edit the question later this morning, since the OP refined their post to make their intentions more clear. However, I had received a follow request and a message in my "Invite Box" on Facebook to answer the question, in addition to a notification I had received from the Stack Exchange site. Said user had found my personal Facebook profile and requested that I update an answer to my question.

[image: Facebook Invite]

StackOverflow disables users from sending unsolicited chat notifications to avoid problems similar to this, and I would preferrably like to be contacted via the comment notification, I was wondering how I should respond to this. Should I delete my answer since it is no longer relevant and avoid answering the question? Should I update my answer to the proper solution? It makes no sense to flag the post, especially given that the message in question occurred outside of the StackOverflow network.

Comment: Be careful that this won't turn into a "chameleon" question, where the OP keeps changing it and keeps begging for help. Personally I would only respond to Stack Exchange requests if they happen _within_ the Stack Exchange system.

Comment: Off topic, but why did you put a link to non-existent twitter account in your profile?

Comment: @ShadowWizard, I actually had a public Twitter account, but then I removed it. I also changed the username. Although, I'm unsure where that account is listed, so any help would be nice to remove it.

Comment: It's still in your [SO profile](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4131059/alexander-huszagh). In the [Edit Profile page](http://stackoverflow.com/users/edit/current), it should be under "Web presence" section.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is really up to you. Your options, in my opinion, are:

- Ignore the request, do nothing, move on, and if user try again, block him.
- Let the user know it's not appropriate to contact you via Facebook, either by accepting the request and sending private message back, or via a comment on his question on SO.
- Respond to the request, help the poor soul, and when it's all done update your answer to reflect everything you've done, for the sake of others with the same issue.

For the record, the user found you because you're using your real name, which is not very common, as the display name. Simple Googling is enough:

> [image]

And visiting that profile easily confirms it's really you. So, to avoid those things in the future, just use an alias or nickname as the display name.

Comment: Yes, I knew this would be a concern, and I considered it. This might change my desire to use an alias. I don't think anything malicious was intended, and I think the user is just hitting a metaphorical brick wall and may have used an inappropriate channel to do so.

Thank you.

Comment: I always thought Shadow Wizard was your real name...

Comment: @Pat well my wife sometimes call me Wizard... ;)

Comment: Mine calls me Pat sometimes ;) @sha

Comment: Alternatively, don't use your real name on social media. It's also what potential clients/employers find when they google you.

Comment: @S.L.Barth hard to do. I'm pretty sure I've seen somewhere that Facebook and Google+ block nick names. Not sure how, i.e. if white list or black list, but pretty sure "Shadow Wizard" will be blocked on both with a friendly message "Sorry but you must use your real name". People with weird names sometimes have to send their passport just to prove it's real.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Depends. Obvious nicknames probably won't work. Variants of one's name can work, or one's name in a different language ("Peter"->"Pjotr"). I've known a few cases of people who used entirely different names.

Comment: @ShadowWizard, I've actually been reported for using false names before (I  had a fake middle name), so I am unable to change my FB account. Although, I'm planning on cleaning up my FB months before any job search (I have a few years of graduate school left though).